# Play Random Sounds when a button is pressed Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, file, audio, random

I have all the code for the app done except for this: I want to make a button play random sound files when pressed.

I found the following code, which it compiles but the button, when pressed, it doesn't do anything. Can someone take a look at it and see what is wrong? I get a time out error when playing the app in the simulator.

You can find the code below:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton1: UIButton!

    // PUT SOUNDS AS STRINGS IN ARRAY
    var arrayOfSounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4"]

    // Different Block of code below.
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: NSString, type: NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer? {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
        return audioPlayer
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
        let range: UInt32 = UInt32(arrayOfSounds.count)
        let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

        let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(arrayOfSounds[number], type: "wav")
        sound!.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some small changes and your, and now it works fine.

I am using a single audioPlayer reference, setting in the function, and then if not null, playing it.

You can also call the function to play the sound, if you move the audioPlayer and the .play() to the method

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton1: UIButton!

    var arrayOfSounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4"]
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

    func setupAudioPlayer(file: NSString, type: NSString){
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        do {
            try  audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
        let range: UInt32 = UInt32(arrayOfSounds.count)
        let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

        self.setupAudioPlayer(arrayOfSounds[number], type: "wav")
        self.audioPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer should explain what was wrong and what changes you made. Don't just post code with no explanation.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this code with the changes and will let you know.

Comment: It looks like it works, but when I connect the button and run the app, when the button is pressed, it won't do anything and then I would get the following message in the debugger: 2016-03-07 06:58:14.893 iMexican[60597:2332212] 06:58:14.892 ERROR:    181: timed out after 0.012s (1721 1722); mMajorChangePending=0

Comment: The code works, so thank you! The only thing is that I keep getting that time out error, even though everything works and keep working. Maybe it has to do with how fast I'm pressing the button. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you sound its too long for a button, or tapping to fast, what you can check is if its playing, before play again. If the answer was helpful you can tag as a accepted , http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer